# How to read post parameters send from android in c#

Tags: c#, android, http-post

I have an android app which sends post data to a server, here is my code :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Server.currentServer + "/mainmenu_mobile.aspx");

    try {
        menuItems = null;

        boolean status = false;
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("auth", Util.Token()));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AppID", Util.AppID));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 201)
        {
            String result = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());  

            InputStream inStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuObject>();

            parser.parse(inStream);     

        }           

        try
        {
            response.getEntity().consumeContent();
        }
        catch (Exception g)
        {

        }

        log.i(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"");
        status = true;

        return status;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return false;
    }
```

How should i read these parameters on server in c#? I need to read each of them separetaly. Also is there any way to seethe values of the data sent with post so as to be sure these data is correct?
Here is mainmenu_mobile.aspx so far:

```
using ClassLibrary1;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using TiboServer_2;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;

public partial class mainmenu_mobile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Util util = new Util();

        Dictionary<String, String> postParams = util.checkHeader(Request, new String[] { "auth", "AppID", "locale" });

        util.check(Request.UserAgent, constant.PAGECODE_MAINMENU, Request.UserHostAddress);

        if (util.RESPONSE == constant.RESPONSE_ACCESS_GRANTED && util.STATE == constant.STATE_INSERTED_SUCCESFULY)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Params.Add("@username", util.username);
            Params.Add("@locale", postParams["locale"]);

            String sql = "select title, url, icon, menucode from mobilemenu where locale = '" + postParams["locale"] + "' order by position asc FOR XML RAW ('menu'), ROOT ('mainmenu'), ELEMENTS";

            //xtr.WhitespaceHandling = System.Xml.WhitespaceHandling.None;
            XmlDocument doc = db_Action.getXmlDocument(sql,Params);

            if (doc != null)
            {
                Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; //must be 'text/xml' 
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; //we'd like UTF-8 
                doc.Save(Response.Output); //save to the text-writer 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 403;
        }
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

and Util.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using ClassLibrary1;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Util
/// </summary>
/// 

namespace TiboServer_2
{
    public class Util
    {  

        //public static String loggingtable = "Server=tcp:jmyvkj5sxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=tibonalytics_db;User ID=TiboDb@jmyvkj5sxx;Password=Tibo2015;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";
        public int RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_NO_RESPONSE;
        public int STATE = constant.STATE_BEGIN;
        public String username = "";
        public String appid = "-1";
        public String App_id;
        public String token;


        private String passwordkey = "";

        public Dictionary<String,String> checkHeader(HttpRequest Request,String[] Params)
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> postParameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            foreach (String param in Params)
            {
                if (Request.Form[param] == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                postParameters.Add(param, Request.Form[param]);
            }

            App_id = postParameters["AppID"];
            token = postParameters["auth"];

            return postParameters;
        }
        public Dictionary<String, String> checkHeader(HttpRequest Request, String[] Params,Boolean[] optional)
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> postParameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            for(int i=0;i<Params.Length;i++)
            {
                String param = Params[i];
                if (Request.Form[param] == null && !optional[i])
                {
                    return null;
                }
                postParameters.Add(param, Request.Form[param]);
            }

            App_id = postParameters["AppID"];
            token = postParameters["auth"];

            return postParameters;
        }

        public Dictionary<String, String> checkHeader(HttpRequest Request, String[] Params, int[] Validate)
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> postParameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Params.Length; i++)
            {
                String param = Params[i];
                if (Request.Form[param] == null)
                {
                    return null;
                } 
                else if (Validate[i] == validate.INTEGER)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Convert.ToInt32(param);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else if (Validate[i] == validate.DOUBLE)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Convert.ToDouble(param);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                postParameters.Add(param, Request.Form[param]);
            }

            App_id = postParameters["AppID"];
            token = postParameters["auth"];

            return postParameters;
        }
        public Dictionary<String, String> checkHeader(HttpRequest Request, String[] Params, int[] Validate,Boolean[] optional)
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> postParameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Params.Length; i++)
            {
                String param = Params[i];
                if (Request.Form[param] == null && !optional[i])
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else if (Validate[i] == validate.INTEGER)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Convert.ToInt32(param);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else if (Validate[i] == validate.DOUBLE)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Convert.ToDouble(param);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                postParameters.Add(param, Request.Form[param]);
            }

            App_id = postParameters["AppID"];
            token = postParameters["auth"];

            return postParameters;
        }

        public void check(String UserAgent, int pageCode, String IP)
        {
            Encryption ee = new Encryption();
            String Token = "";

            try
            {
                appid = ee.Decrypt(App_id, constant.AppID_Key);
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_UNABLE_TO_DECRYPT_APPID;
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Token = ee.Decrypt(token, constant.EK);
            }
            catch (Exception f)
            {
                RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_UNABLE_TO_DECRYPT_TOKEN;
                return;
            }

            string[] Token_Content = Token.Split(';');

            username = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Token_Content[0].Trim());
            String password = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Token_Content[1].Trim());
            String epochetime = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Token_Content[2].Trim());

            try
            {
                username = ee.Decrypt(username, constant.UsernameKey);
            }
            catch
            {
                RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_UNABLE_TO_DECRYPT_USERNAME;
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                epochetime = ee.Decrypt(epochetime, constant.TimeKey);
            }
            catch
            {
                RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_UNABLE_TO_DECRYPT_EPOCHTIME;
                return;
            }

            Dictionary<String,String> Params = new Dictionary<String,String>();
            Params.Add("@username", username);

            String query;
            if (appid == "1")
            {
                query = "select videokey,id from login where username = @username and lockaccount = 0";
            }
            else
            {
                query = "select mobilevideokey,id from login where username = @username and lockaccount = 0";
            }

            DataTable dt = db_Action.ExecuteQuery(query, Params);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                passwordkey = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();   //videokey
            }

            long id = (int)dt.Rows[0][1];     //id


            if (username == "promo")
            {
                RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_ACCESS_GRANTED;
                STATE = constant.STATE_INSERTED_SUCCESFULY;
            }
            else
            {

                try
                {
                    password = ee.Decrypt(password, passwordkey);
                }
                catch
                {
                    RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_UNABLE_TO_DECRYPT_PASSWORD;
                    return;
                }

                RESPONSE = constant.RESPONSE_ACCESS_GRANTED;

                Params.Add("@code",appid + "_" + pageCode + "_" + id + "_" + epochetime);
                String query = "insert into Monitor (code) Values(@code)";


                try
                {
                    db_Action.ExecuteSingleQuery(query, Params);
                    STATE = constant.STATE_INSERTED_SUCCESFULY;
                }
                catch
                {
                    STATE = constant.STATE_DUBLICATE_CALL;
                    Params.Clear();
                    Params.Add("@username", username);
                    Params.Add("@code",  appid + "_" + pageCode + "_" + id + "_" + epochetime + "_" + (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds + "_" + IP);
                    Params.Add("@value",UserAgent);
                    query = "insert into Monitor (code,value) Values(@code,@value)";
                    db_Action.ExecuteSingleQuery(query, Params);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to program a complete webserver in C# or only a cgi executable in C#?

Comment: `mainmenu_mobile.aspx`. Probably only for this active server page?

Comment: My android app sends post parameters to server just as described above, but I am not sure on the server side how to read these params. I need them for authentification

Comment: yes mainmenu_mobile.aspx should read these parameters

Comment: Well show the code you have already.

Comment: I updated the post with the whole code

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_server_side.htm

Comment: Well you are reading them already. And more than once it looks like. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: the response is constant.RESPONSE_UNABLE_TO_DECRYPT_APPID??

Comment: You did not say on what. `App_id = postParameters["AppID"];
            token = postParameters["auth"];`. Please tell the value of `App_id` and `token`. Use a function first who deliver those variables.

Comment: app_id is an encripted number and token is an encrypted string which contains username, password and a key. These values are different on every request

Comment: Can be.. But you know what you send. So just check if what you send is what you receive.

Comment: You could as a test put fixed unencrypted data in it so you know exactly what you have to receive. You could also add some extra name value pairs. How about 'locale'?

Comment: I found that the first parameter is sent twice, but cant understand why